# PSQL: Aggregate function (sum) not working

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, psql

I have this query (`artist_money` is of  `MONEY` type, e.g. `$30,456.11`.):

```
SELECT SUM(
CASE
WHEN end_date - date '2015-12-3' <= 28 AND end_date - date '2015-12-3' > 0 THEN artist_money
END,
CASE
WHEN date '2015-12-3' - start_date > 28 THEN artist_money
END
) AS "gonorar"
FROM peacecard 
WHERE artist_id = 12345 AND contract IS NOT NULL
```

When I try to get the result, here's the error:

```
ERROR:  function sum(money, money) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT sum(
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********
```

What's going on? According to [Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-aggregate.html), `SUM` should take the parameters if it's `MONEY` type.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the comma, not the money type.  Perhaps you intend:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN end_date - date '2015-12-3' <= 28 AND end_date - date '2015-12-03' > 0
                THEN artist_money
           END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN date '2015-12-3' - start_date > 28
                THEN artist_money
           END
          ) AS "gonorar"
FROM peacecard 
WHERE artist_id = 12345 AND contract IS NOT NULL;
```

Or, if you want one column, then it makes much more sense to only use one `case`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN end_date - date '2015-12-3' <= 28 AND end_date - date '2015-12-03' > 0
                THEN artist_money
                WHEN date '2015-12-3' - start_date > 28
                THEN artist_money
           END
          ) AS "gonorar"
FROM peacecard 
WHERE artist_id = 12345 AND contract IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: It has to be `sum(money)`, not `sum(money, money)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to pass two parameters to an aggregate 1 parameter function.